# Linear interpolation using pycuda (lerp)

Tags: python, cuda, interpolation, pycuda

I am a recreational pythonista who just got into pyCUDA. I am trying to figure out how to implement a linear interpolation (lerp) using pyCUDA. The CUDA CG function is: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/lerp.html

My ultimate goal  is a bilinear interpolation in pycuda from a set of weighted random points. I've never programmed C, or CUDA for that matter, and am learning as I go.

This is how far I've gotten:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.compiler as comp

lerpFunction = """__global__ float lerp(float a, float b, float w)
{
    return a + w*(b-a);
}"""

mod = comp.SourceModule(lerpFunction) # This returns an error telling me a global must return a void. :(
```

Any help on this would be fantastic!

Comment: What does `__global__` do? Why do you think you need it?

Comment: @MarkRansom: This is CUDA and it is necessary -  `__global__` denotes to the NVIDIA compiler driver that the function is gpu code.

Comment: If you want to further explore CUDA on Python, try this one out. http://www.accelereyes.com/afpy.html

Comment: Thanks Pavan! I've been fiddling with that code all weekend to see what all I could get it to do interpolation wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty explicit - CUDA kernels cannot return values, they must be declared `void`, and modifiable arguments passed as pointers. It would make more sense for your lerp implementation to be declared as a device function like this:

```
__device__ float lerp(float a, float b, float w)
{
    return a + w*(b-a);
}
```

and then called from inside a kernel for each value that requires interpolation. Your lerp function lacks a lot of "infrastructure" to be a useful CUDA kernel.

---

EDIT: A really basic kernel along the same lines might look something like this:

```
__global__ void lerp_kernel(const float *a, const float *b, const float w, float *y)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x; // unique thread number in the grid
    y[tid] = a[tid] + w*(b[tid]-a[tid]);
}
```

Comment: so, something more along these lines?  pycuda.elementwise.ElementwiseKernel("float a,float b,float w","return a+b+w","lerp")

Comment: No that still has the same problem - kernels functions can't return values. This isn't like old fashioned shader language, memory acces is done via pointers passed as function argument. It sounds like you should read some documentation or look at one of the vast number of introductory tutorials which the search engine of your choice will find for you if you choose to search.